# Is there a way of extending the functionality of basic Lexical nodes?

Tags: javascript, class, prototypal-inheritance, lexicaljs

I know I can [create custom nodes](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/nodes#creating-custom-nodes) that are an extension of inbuilt node classes. And it works great, But I would also like to extend the functionality of inbuilt classes themselves.

For example, I have this helper function:

```js
import { LexicalNode } from 'lexical'

function insertMultipleAfter(targetNode: LexicalNode, nodesToInsert: LexicalNode[]) {
  ;[...nodesToInsert].reverse().forEach(node => targetNode.insertAfter(node))
}
```

and I would like to make it part of `LexicalNode` itself, so I can call `node.insertMultipleAfter(arrayOfNodes)` on any node of any type - or perhaps even add a new overload to `insertAfter` to make it also handle an array.

Is there a "correct" way to do this? Or is it not advisable, and should I stick to my helper functions?

Comment: I've got the same question, but in relation to the `RootNode`. It's always safe to use your own ElementNode extensions, but what if I want to override the `exportDOM` method of the RootNode?

Comment: You can always monkey patch